# Capybara won't select item from select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I'm using Capybara to test a little Web app I'm writing. It refuses to select the right item from a select. Here's the code:

```
  before do
    fill_in 'Assignment', with: "blah blah blah"
    select student.name, from: "assignment[student_id]"
  end
```

I've tried every supported format in the "from" field. I've used the id, the name, and the label text to try and select the correct element. I've even booted the rails server in test, and manually ran through the steps in my test in the console. No matter what I do, capybara kicks back:

```
cannot select option, no option with text 'John Doe' in select box 'assignment[student_id]'
```

As stated before, I have kicked up the rails server in the test environment, and then manually added users to the database the same way I have done in my tests. I am 100% confident of the fact that there is indeed an option with text 'John Doe' in select box 'assignment[student].' This leads me to believe that I must be using the select method incorrectly. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Can you add the code for the select box, just to be doubly sure.

Comment: Try to run something like `all('#assignment[student_id] > option').each {|el| puts el.text(:all)}` to check if such option exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the select `from:` need the select fields name or the ID? 
Try it with the ID instead (assuming standard form style):

```
select student.name, from: "assignment_student_id"
```

If you inspect source on the select element you can confirm the fields ID.

Does it use the value of the option element rather than the text? Again, inspect and see what the value of "John Doe" is and see if it works by using student.id.

```
select student.id, from: "assignment[student_id]"
```

Lastly, have you tried the syntax in the documentation that includes the page?

```
page.select student.name, :from => 'assignment[student_id]'
```

Comment: If `select` doesn't find element by name, it won't also find it by id since [this method supports either of them](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method).

Comment: Also `select` inspects only text of the option so your second advice is incorrect too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the select code. I forgot how FactoryGirl's let works. I called build through a relationship on a User created by Factory Girl, and then tried assigning that result to student via let. Unfortunately, since let is lazy, it wasn't being created when it needed to be, so basically the page was getting called up before the student object was even created. I moved the code in my let statement into a before, and then assigned student using let and User.students.first.